# How exactly do two powerline adapters search & connect to each other?

Tags: powerline-networking, network-protocols

Could someone please explain how exactly two powerline adapters "search" and "connect to" each other?

*(As far as I know, the manual pairing of two adapters is only necessary to exchange the decryption key, right?)*

If this connecting process includes some kind of broadcast, will it still be active/sending with only one adapter plugged into the wall-mounted socket outlet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, PowerLine adapters are functioning according to 7-layer OSI model and the only difference from conventional Ethernet is Layer 1 (Physical Layer). [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) is implemented on Layer 2 (Data Layer) and should not be different for PowerLine.

For details on the protocol try to look up HomePLug protocol family that includes

- HomePlug 1.0
- HomePlug AV
- HomePlug AV2
- HomePlug Green PHY
- HomePlug Access BPL

Your assumption about pairing is correct. It is only used for two adapters to exchange encryption key. Most adapters that come in pairs will be pre-programmed with identical network key. However all of them (should be all, but I am not sure) - implement a feature of configuring a key. Note that this does not include encryption of Your data. It only refers to encryption of communication between PowerLine adapters. [This article on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug#Security) provides a good summary of security features of HomePlug protocols.

As for your last question, I believe it is the same as for any network. Yes - broadcast packets will be sent even if only one adapter is connected (this is how broadcast works). However no data will be sent over network before communication is established and secure.